# Create my own notifyDataSetChanged in an Adapter that does not extend BaseAdapter

Tags: android

in an Android application I develop, I have to use a provided Adapter (e.g. Adapter1) that only implements android.widget.Adapter and android.widget.ListAdapter (it does not extend BaseAdapter). This adapter is used in many ListViews of the application.

I would like to have the auto filtering feature in the ListViews to which I attach the adapter,  so I decided to create new class (e.g. Adapter2) that extends Adapter1 and implements the Filterable interface. But after I filter my data based on the user input I cannot notify the attached view to redraw itself since there is no notifyDataSetChanged() method provided, since as I noted the provided Adapter does not extend BaseAdapter.

How can I create a similar method in my class that does the work?
Is there any other suggestion?

Thank you in advance,
Bill